# configure: error: Python.h not found when it exists in Ubuntu 18

Tags: python, c++, configure

I am trying to run a `./configure --with-python` file (I can attach it but it's long) and I am getting these errors:

```
checking for gtest-config... no
File "<string>", line 1
import distutils.sysconfig; bl = distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('BLDLIBRARY'); print bl if bl   else '-lpython2.7'
                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
File "<string>", line 1
import distutils.sysconfig; print distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('INCLUDEPY')
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
checking Python.h usability... no
checking Python.h presence... no
checking for Python.h... no
configure: error: Python.h not found. Please install the devel package.
```

Next step, I run: `locate Python.h` which gives me:

```
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h
/usr/include/python3.7m/Python.h
```

Next step, I run each of these:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.7
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.6m
./configure --with-python=/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h
```

With no luck.

Any pointers on where the error can be? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `CFLAGS`

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.7 CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/python2.7/
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it was a problem with the CFLAG and it was also a problem with the CMAKE file. It was expecting Python 2.7 while the system had 3.6 installed by default. So at the end I had to apply a patch to the CMAKe and also add the CFLAG. Thanks!!